# Run C# Application in Different Language using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resources, vmargs

I have an application which has several resource files for different languages depending on the machines culture/language. This works fine if i set the Culture using code, but I am wanting to specify the culture on the command line somehow.

I know in java you simply need to set the VM Args lang attributes and the application starts up in that language, but I am unsure if this is possible using Visual Studio as it doesnt have this type of option.

Can anyone provide a non code solution, I know i could set some cmd line args to read in the lang and then set it using a bit of code but I am wanting to know if there is another way.

I also dont want to keep switching my language using my machine setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cultures are a .NET specific thing, picked up at run-time from the current users 'Locale'.  This can be changed by a user at runtime, on a per-application basis.

The default 'Execute Process' functionality does not really support this, a Microsoft utility exists "AppLoc" which adds this functionality.  There is an article available on CodeProject [Running AppLoc from Batch Files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25269/Running-the-Microsoft-AppLocale-Utility-in-an-Auto) explains how to better control this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to set this using cmd line args? 
You could just use current thread CurrentUICulture property to get it.

Comment: I know this. This is what I am currently doing, but I was "wondering" if you could do it using some sort of cmd line args the way that eclipse lets java applications be set.